# Getting Application Defined or User Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am racking my brain to figure out why i get an Error 1004 on this. I have a worksheet with unique identifiers that I need to find in another worksheet then return a value in a different column on the row and it seemed WorksheetFunction.Index+Match. The data I need is offset by one column (hence the Count_2 - 1). I have declared the variables and even unlocked the sheets just in case. I know I could use index match within excel but I am trying to use vba for all calculations so that end users can't mess anything up and so that it will be easier to see what the workbook is actually doing. Any ideas?

Separately I have been setting it to print out a number to a specific cell so I can more easily see where the code is dying.

```
For Count_1 = 2 to 51

    For Count_2 = 4 To 44

        Sheet8.Cells(Count_1, Count_2) = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet7.Range(Cells(47, Count_2 -1), _
        Cells(904, Count_2 - 1)), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet8.Cells(Count_1, 1).Value, _
        Sheet7.Range("A47:A904"), 0))

        Count_3 = Count_3 + 1
        Sheet1.Range("D1") = 2

    Next

Next
```

Comment: `Cells` does not refer to the same sheet as `Sheet7.Range` you must specify a worksheet for *every* `Cells` object too. Like: `…Sheet7.Range(Sheet7.Cells(47, …` • Also `WorksheetFunction.Match` will throw an error if nothing mached. So you need to catch that case and decide what to do in case nothing matches.

Comment: Which line of code is triggering the error? The code in the question doesn't provide enough context for anyone to see it without at least that information... The error is telling you there's something in the code that's "spelled wrong" or doesn't exist in the object model.

Comment: Here the error 1004 occurs because `Match` doesn't find anything.

Comment: I added .Value to the cell it is supposed to match to, now it says that the Match is an invalid qualifier

Comment: @East If you changed something on the code you must be more clear what you changed and [edit] this into your question. Otherwise it is hard to see what the actual code is now.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Cells(47, …` does not refer to the same sheet as `Sheet7.Range` you must specify a worksheet for every `Cells` object too. Like: `…Sheet7.Range(Sheet7.Cells(47, …`
2. `WorksheetFunction.Match` will throw an error if nothing mached. So you need to catch that case and decide what to do in case nothing matches.
3. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and declare all your variables properly.
4. Numbered variable names like `Count_1` and `Count_2` are pretty shitty, because the get mixed up quickly. Instead always use meaningful variable names like `iRow` and `iColumn`.

So you will end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim CellsProcedured As Long

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To 51

        Dim iColumn As Long
        For iColumn = 4 To 44

            Dim MatchResult As Double
            On Error GoTo NO_MATCH
            MatchResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet8.Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Sheet7.Range("A47:A904"), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0

            On Error GoTo NO_INDEX
            Sheet8.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet7.Range(Sheet7.Cells(47, iColumn - 1), Sheet7.Cells(904, iColumn - 1)), MatchResult)
            On Error GoTo 0

            CellsProcedured = CellsProcedured + 1
            Sheet1.Range("D1") = 2

        Next iColumn
    Next iRow


    Exit Sub

NO_MATCH:
    MsgBox "The value '" & Sheet8.Cells(iRow, 1).Value & "' was not found in Range A47:A904. Aborting."

    Exit Sub

NO_INDEX:
    MsgBox "Index failed at cell(" & iRow & ", " & iColumn & "). Aborting."
End Sub
```

Comment: Well damn.  I can't figure out why match isn't working then, The columns are correct, I did the Sheet7.Cells() change, and it already has an Option Explicit whic i have enabled by default.

Comment: @East Make sure the cell value it is supposed to match has no additional spaces (or other text) before or after the value itself. Check the output of `Debug.Print Sheet8.Cells(iRow, 1).Value` and see if you can find it manually in `Sheet7.Range("A47:A904")`

Comment: I can find it manually. The value to match is a CAS number and an example of the format is 107-04-0 (1-bromo-2-chloroethane if you are curious) and the values to find are a series of classifications and values for different parameters.  Is the .value needed for this or something else in its place?

Comment: @ Pᴇʜ if i change the reference cell formatting to Text from General would that help at all?

Comment: I did something but I have no idea what exactly. It it runs through like it should though.

Comment: @East Actually if you enter CAS numbers it might be possible that Excel treats them as dates. For example if your cell format is `General` then enter something like `20-04-2` as (valid) CAS number and my german Excel treats it as a date `20.04.2002`. So it is absolutely necessary to set the cells to `Text` as number format. Also the cell that contains the lookup value needs to be `Text`.

Comment: Appreciate the help man, I was able to get it working. It turns out it was a combination of cell formatting and references in index match malfunctioning/returning an error.  Fixed it with a simple If IsError().

Comment: @East If you solved it differently than my answer you can post your solution as answer and then mark your own answer as solution to the question. So it might help further readers who have similar issues, and you gain some credits for it.